# MySQL: Join to get all data with same timestamp on a row

Tags: mysql

I have a table, tempData, looking like this:

```
+----------+-------+------+---------------------+
| sensorId | temp  | hum  | sampleTime          |
+----------+-------+------+---------------------+
|       11 | 18.80 |   55 | 2015-01-19 22:10:01 |
|       11 | 18.80 |   55 | 2015-01-19 22:15:01 |
|       11 | 18.80 |   55 | 2015-01-19 22:20:01 |
|       21 | 20.00 |   51 | 2015-01-19 22:10:01 |
|       21 | 20.10 |   50 | 2015-01-19 22:15:01 |
|       21 | 20.00 |   51 | 2015-01-19 22:20:01 |
|       31 | 16.10 |   59 | 2015-01-19 22:10:01 |
|       31 | 16.20 |   59 | 2015-01-19 22:15:01 |
|       31 | 16.20 |   59 | 2015-01-19 22:20:01 |
|       41 |  6.30 |   91 | 2015-01-19 22:10:01 |
|       41 |  6.30 |   91 | 2015-01-19 22:15:01 |
|       41 |  6.30 |   91 | 2015-01-19 22:20:01 |
+----------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

I'm looking for the query that will give me one table with two sensors on the same row (e.i. 11 and 21) grouped by sampleTime:

```
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| temp_11 | hum_11 | temp_21 | hum_21 | sampleTime          |
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|  18.80  |   55   |  20.00  |   51   | 2015-01-19 22:10:01 |
|  18.80  |   55   |  20.10  |   50   | 2015-01-19 22:15:01 |
|  18.80  |   55   |  20.00  |   51   | 2015-01-19 22:20:01 |
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

regards,
Fredrik

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also it would be helpful, but not necessary, to know the datatypes you are using in the table.

Comment: Rhumborl's answer solved it. The datatypes are smallint, decimal(5,2), tinyint and datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 subqueries and join them:

```
select [temp_11], [hum_11], [temp_21], [hum_21], sensor11.sampleTime
(
    -- get sensor 11 details
    select temp as [temp_11], hum as [hum_11], sampleTime
        from tempData
        where sensorId = 11
) sensor11
inner join
(
    -- get sensor 21 details
    select temp as [temp_21], hum as [hum_21], sampleTime
        from tempData
        where sensorId = 21
) sensor21 on sensor11.sampleTime = sensor21.sampleTime
```

Or slightly neater, a self-join:

```
select
    sensor11.temp as [temp_11],
    sensor11.hum as [hum_11],
    sensor21.temp as [temp_21],
    sensor21.hum as [hum_21],
    sensor11.sampleTime
from tempData sensor11
inner join tempData sensor21 on sensor11.sampleTime = sensor21.sampleTime
    and sensor21.sensorId = 21
where sensor11.sensorId = 11
```

If you want to include other sensors, just keep adding `join`s:

```
select
    sensor11.temp as [temp_11],
    sensor11.hum as [hum_11],
    sensor21.temp as [temp_21],
    sensor21.hum as [hum_21],
    sensor31.temp as [temp_31], -- add
    sensor31.hum as [hum_31], -- add
    sensor11.sampleTime
from tempData sensor11
inner join tempData sensor21 on sensor11.sampleTime = sensor21.sampleTime
    and sensor21.sensorId = 21
inner join tempData sensor31 on sensor11.sampleTime = sensor31.sampleTime -- add
    and sensor31.sensorId = 31 -- add
where sensor11.sensorId = 11
```

Comment: Is it easy to expand the inner join to include several , ni this case, sensors? I would like to include sensor 31.